# How to run an application with elevated privileges

Tags: sudo, vs-code

I have installed VS Code on my Pi. Now I see a problem, I cannot edit and save all the files. Like files that I used to update using nano editor inside the config folders, cannot be edited and saved using VS Code.

For running the command-line editor, we could just run it under `Sudo` and it was done.

Currently, I am trying to develop a theme for Wordpress and I am stuck as I cannot use VS-Code for this as I cannot save files inside /var/www/html/ folder or sub-folder without using sudo.

How may I do it for VS Code?

Comment: You should not be using VS Code to edit those configuration files.  I thought it was intended for software development.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to develop a theme for Wordpress and I am stuck as I cannot use VS-Code for this as I cannot save files inside /var/www/html/ folder or sub-folder without using sudo.

Comment: The permission system is there for a reason.  I don't know what to suggest but the question is not Pi specific.

Comment: You can either run VS Code as the user who owns the files (for `/var/www` I suppose it's `www-data`), or change the file permissions to make them editable by the current user.

Comment: or edit them in your home directory and then copy them and change ownership and permissions.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The whole question is about what you suggested. But how may I run VS code either as www-data or under sudo?

Comment: `sudo -u www-data CMD`... You could also add yourself to the group that owns the directory.. or just change the permissions or even change the owner. I sometimes run code-oss as root with sudo and it works fine.

Comment: Personally I would create a new dir in my dev dir and when I'm done I would `sudo cp -r XXX YYY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you are trying to do this as user `pi`, but the same method applies for anyone.  As others have said, running VS code as root probably isn't a great idea. Instead you want to give the VS code user access to the relevant directories.

Get the permissions and ownership set on the directory you want.  For example:

```
> stat /var/www

  File: /var/www
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 803h/2051d      Inode: 1716748     Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1028/     foo)   Gid: ( 1028/     foo)
Access: 2021-02-01 10:08:08.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2021-02-01 10:08:08.000000000 -0500
Change: 2021-02-23 16:41:13.431801967 -0500
 Birth: 2018-04-12 12:27:12.113737308 -0400
```

In this case it is owned by user `foo`, group `foo`, permission mode is 0755 meaning anyone can read but only the owner can write.  Change this to allow other users in group `foo` to write:

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www
```

Now, add user pi to the `foo` group:

```
sudo usermod -G foo pi
```

This will be effective when `pi` next logs in.  In theory since it increases access it opens up a vulnerability -- but chances are there was no one in group `foo` besides user `foo`, so this is in theory only.  To check that:

```
> grep foo /etc/group
foo:x:1028:pi
```

The users in the group, except for `foo`, are shown after the last colon.

An alternative is to change the group ownership of the directory:

```
> chgrp pi /var/www
```

Again, since `foo` still has write access, nothing else will have changed besides granting it to those in group `pi` -- which is probably just `pi`.

You can read more about the commands used via (eg.) `man chgrp`.

Comment: thank you so much for the great explanation and directions. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a "chown" and "chmod" issue with the directory you are trying to "write/save" to.  Have you tried this on the directory you want to save into?